# Changing the contentView when an Accessory button is tapped

Tags: ios, layout, uitableview

I've subclassed `UITableViewCell` to display a `UIImage` and two `UILabel` subviews. In the view controller for the table view, in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I've enabled an accessory view via `setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`.

Cells display correctly.

When I tap on the accessory disclosure button I want to replace the two label subviews with two different label subviews. My approach was the following:

1. In the subclassed `UITableViewCell`, inside `layoutSubviews`, create the
   `CGRect`s for the "alternate" labels, position them in the same
   places as the two "original" label and hide them via `setAlpha:`;
2. When the disclosure button is tapped swap out the set of two
   label by adjusting their respective alphas.

The problem is I can't figure out what logic in `layoutSubviews` I'd use to know whether the accessory button has been tapped. I see that in the view controller `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` is called when that button is tapped and from there it seems like I would call `layoutSubviews` but can't figure out how to use that fact to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Am I going about this all wrong? Instead of hiding/showing `CGRect`s with alpha should I simply be creating another subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I tap on the accessory disclosure button I want to replace the two UILabel subviews with two different UILabel subviews.

I'll do the following. Create a public method in your `UITableViewCell` subclass like the following:

```
- (void)changeContentForCell;
```

In this method you could set the `contentView` as you prefer.

Then in your view controller implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cCell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cCell changeContentForCell];
}
```

This is a simple example for change the content. In my opinion you don't have to use `layoutSubviews` to add views.

Leave this logic in `changeContentForCell` and then call `setNeedsLayout` to change your layout. Maybe you could have a variable that tracks the state for your cell: normal state or modified state.

Hope it helps.